# Prove that $f$ is holomorphic in $U$ (second part)

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

This is the natural continuation of [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706788/let-f-in-cu-bbb-c-holomorphic-on-u-setminus-l-show-that-f-is-holomorph). I have this exercise

> Let $L:=a+\Bbb R b$, for some $a,b\in\Bbb C$, a straight line in $\Bbb C$. Also let $f\in C(U,\Bbb C)$ is holomorphic on $U\setminus L$. Show that $f$ is holomorphic on all of $U$. (Hint: Morera's theorem.)

I want to know is the proof below is correct or if there is some mistake or it is incomplete.

The version of Morera's theorem that I used here use only triangular paths $\Delta$, where a triangular path is a closed path defined by the straight segments between three different points whenever the region bounded by the triangle belongs to the domain of the function.

It says

> **Morera's theorem:** if $\int_\Delta f dz=0$ for every triangular path in $U$ then $f$ is analytic in $U$.

---

**The proof:**

Observe that we need to consider just the analyticity of $f$ on $U\cap L$.

Then we only need to see what happen to the paths that contain some point of $U\cap L$. There are three kinds of triangular paths $\Delta$ that contain a point of $U\cap L$:

1. $|\Delta\cap L|=1$, then necessarily this point is a vertex of $\Delta$.
2. $|\Delta\cap L|=2$, then there is a segment of $L$ inside the area bounded by $\Delta$.
3. $|\Delta\cap L|=\mathfrak c$, then there is a whole segment of $\Delta$ contained in $L$.

Let a homotopy $H\in C^1([0,1]^2,U)$ such that each $H([0,1],t)$ is triangular. Now I want to show that if $f$ is continuous then the map $t\mapsto\int_{\Delta_t}f(z)\, dz$ is also continuous, where $\Delta_t:=H([0,1],t)$. Then
$$
\left|\int_{\Delta_{t_1}} f(z)\, dz-\int_{\Delta_{t_2}}f(z)\, dz\right|=\left|\int_0^1(f\circ H)(s,t_1)\partial_1H(s,t_1)\, ds-\int_0^1(f\circ H)(s,t_2)\partial_1H(s,t_2)\, ds\right|\\
=\left|\int_0^1\big((f\circ H)(s,t_1)\partial_1H(s,t_1)-(f\circ H)(s,t_2)\partial_1H(s,t_2)\big)\, ds\right|\\
\le\max_{s\in[0,1]}|(f\circ H)(s,t_1)\partial_1H(s,t_1)-(f\circ H)(s,t_2)\partial_1H(s,t_2)|\tag1
$$
Now observe that the function $g:=(f\circ H)(\cdot,\cdot)\partial_1 H(\cdot,\cdot)$ is uniformly continuous (because it is a continuous function with compact domain) so for every chosen $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|(s,t_1)-(s,t_2)|=|t_1-t_2|<\delta\implies |g(s,t_1)-g(s,t_2)|<\epsilon\tag2
$$
Consequently the map $t\mapsto\int_{\Delta_t}f(z)\, dz$ is continuous. Thus if we choose $H$ such that $\Delta_t\subset U\setminus L$ for all $t\in[0,1)$ and $\Delta_1\subset U$ then
$$
\int_{\Delta_1}f(z)\, dz=\lim_{t\to 1}\int_{\Delta_t}f(z)\, dz=\lim_{t\to 1}0=0\tag3
$$
Now observe that this hold for every triangular path on $U$ of kind $1$ and $3$ because the interior of the region bounded by these triangles belongs completely to $U\setminus L$, so we can define such $H$ in any case. By last observe that a triangle of kind $2$ can be decomposed in two or three triangular paths of kind $1$ and $3$.

Then $(3)$ holds for every $\Delta_1\subset U$ so, by Morera's theorem, $f$ is analytic in $U$.$\Box$

Comment: What are you assuming about $U$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos that it doesnt have isolated points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not correct. You only considered triangles such that one of its vertices belong to $L$. That's far from being the general case.

Comment: @Masacroso And how do you go from that to the fact that $f$ is analytic?

Comment: @Masacroso Please add to your proof a proof of the fact that $f$ is analytic using the fact that $f|_{U\setminus L}$ is analytic together with the fact that the map $t\mapsto\int_{\Delta_t}f(z)\,\mathrm dz$ is continuous.

Comment: @Masacroso Suppose that $L=\mathbb R$ and that the vertices of your triangle are $i$, $-i$ and $1-i$. How are you going to get a homotopy such that $\Delta_t\subset U\setminus\mathbb R$ when $t\in[0,1)$?

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, they belong to $U$, but not necessarily to $U\setminus\mathbb R$. Again: how are you going to get a homotopy such that $\Delta_t\subset U\setminus\mathbb R$ when $t\in[0,1)$?

Comment: ok, I see what you says. Yes, there is a problem here, I was not think on some kind of triangles, so I need to define an explicit way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: @Masacroso I've edited my answer.

Comment: I rewrote some parts of the proof. there are not all the details but I think it is essentially correct. Basically what I did was use triangularization of a triangle as of your example to reduce the proof to the previous limit, that is, to homotopies such that $\Delta_t\in U\setminus L$ for $t\in[0,1)$

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, decompsing the original triangle in three triangles the way you did, your proof works.